# How to structure a simple program to examine inputs for partial matches using regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create a class to do partial matches using regex. I've got basically i'm lost as to how to perform the search.

The input will come in like "flour#yeast#banana" where # will stand for an unknown length, unknown collection of letters.
The search must keep the order of flour_ _ _ *Yeast* _ _ _Banana. So that matches would include

"flouryeastbanana"

"flouraddyeastmashbanana"

"flouraddyeastbanana"

but not

"yeastflourbanana"

the regex code i'm thinking is **@" ^[a - zA - Z] + $"**

and what i've got so far is

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] input = "flour#yeast#banana".Split('*');
        string[] searchblock = new string[4] { "flouryeastbanana", "flouraddyeastmashbanana", "flouraddyeastbanana", "yeastflourbanana" };
        string pattern = @" ^[a - zA - Z] + $";


        foreach (string s in searchblock)
        {
            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(s, pattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"  (match for '{pattern}' found)");
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

but I cant fathom how to go forward with this nor do i know how to make it search for more than 1/0 random letter... so i'm pretty sure i'm wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just replace the `'*'` in your input string (or is it `'#'`? your question is unclear...the narrative says one thing, the code implies another) with `".*?"` and then use that whole string as your pattern. E.g.:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "flour*yeast*banana";
    string[] searchblock = new string[4] { "flouryeastbanana", "flouraddyeastmashbanana", "flouraddyeastbanana", "yeastflourbanana" };
    string pattern = input.Replace("*", ".*?");

    foreach (string s in searchblock)
    {
        if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(s, pattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"input \"{s}\":  (match for '{pattern}' found)");
        }
    }
}
```

The sequence `".*?"` in the regex says to match any number of any character, with the least number of characters possible that will still allow the match to succeed. By using it in place of your marker in the input string, that allows any string with your non-marker strings separated by any other characters to match.

Note that the `?` in the string is probably optional in your case. It would make a subtle difference with respect to where the matches occurred if you presented the pattern with strings that included the non-marker strings multiple time, but shouldn't affect *whether* the strings actually matched or not. So if you prefer, you could probably just use `".*"` as the replacement text instead of `".*?"`.